# jQuery count elements Start from 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count the elements on page BUT i need the numbers to start from 0 as opposed to 1.

I know I can simply do `var tadada = $('.clickableDiv').length;`

but this will return the numbers from 1.

is this possible using jquery or javascript?

Comment: What about `var tadada = $('.clickableDiv').length - 1;`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If there's one element on the page, `length` being 1 makes sense. Otherwise, you'd have no way to express the fact that there is no matching element on the page (`length = 0`).

Comment: A count starting from zero where zero means 1 makes no sense?!

Comment: `var tadada = $('.clickableDiv').length;` it will provide number of element have same class `clickableDiv`. so if 1 element is there then the code `var tadada = $('.clickableDiv').length - 1;` 
will show 0 which lead to ambiguity,

Comment: @Liam, it actually does make sense when you are using something like Carousel as every carousel count starts from 0. so please do not downvote a valid question!

Comment: @DavidHope: Remember, you have no idea who downvoted, just who commented. They're frequently not the same people.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, fair enough. I only go by what I see and will put the 2 and 2 together ;)

Comment: @DavidHope: In my experience, you'll be wrong a lot more often than right in this particular corrolation/causation assumption. Obligatory humorous link: https://www.xkcd.com/552/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Okie Dokie.. lets stay on the topic of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. If there's one element on the page, `length` being 1 makes sense. Otherwise, you'd have no way to express the fact that there is no matching element on the page (`length = 0`).

**If** you mean you're trying to find their indexes, then you'd just count from `0` through `length - 1`, usually be using `< length` as a loop condition. E.g.:

```js
var foos = $(".foo");
for (var n = 0; n < foos.length; ++n) {
  console.log("#" + n + " is '" + foos.eq(n).text() + "'");
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">First</div>
<div>(not foo)</div>
<div class="foo">Second</div>
<div>(not foo)</div>
<div class="foo">Third</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But you don't want `length` to be `0` when there's one element. It doesn't make sense.

Of course, if you're trying to output numbers in a list or something for human consumption, adding one to the index for *display* purposes is common practice:

```js
var foos = $(".foo");
for (var n = 0; n < foos.length; ++n) {
  console.log((n + 1) + ": '" + foos.eq(n).text() + "'");
  // Adding 1 ^^^^^^^ for display purposes only
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">First</div>
<div>(not foo)</div>
<div class="foo">Second</div>
<div>(not foo)</div>
<div class="foo">Third</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var tadada = $('.clickableDiv').length - 1;
```

Comment: `var tadada = $('.clickableDiv').length;` it will provide number of element have same class `clickableDiv`. so if 1 element is there then the code provided by you will show 0 which lead to ambiguity,